# Build kernel with AOSP

Tags: android, kernel, android-source

I would like to build AOSP code while integrating the kernel as well. I followed these instructions: http://jhshi.me/2014/06/30/build-kernel-in-tree-with-aosp-for-nexus-5-hammerhead/

but they seem to be specific to hammerhead. How would I do a full AOSP build with my custom msm kernel source directory (using flo)?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can follow the official guide [source.android.com/source/building-kernels](https://source.android.com/source/building-kernels.html#figuring-out-which-kernel-to-build)
to build your custom kernel, then move the binary file(zImage) into `device/lge/mako-kernel/`(this path is for Nexus 4) in android source code. This will replace the default kernel file.
Of course you need to change the path which is depends on your device.
Finally, build AOSP as usual.